# Mapfish & Geoserver & Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, mapfish

I'm using Geoserver 2.13.2 with leaflet0.7.2, I have deployed Geoserver Tomcat 9.0 and followed all steps mentioned in [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/) and I have installed mapfish v3.

I'm trying to print a map and wms layers and I'm using the this [plugin](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.print).

But when I start printing I got following problem:

```
      Error while generating PDF:
        com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/ (spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:821)
            at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:277)
            at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page$1.add(Page.java:76)
            at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MapBlock.render(MapBlock.java:81)
            at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:73)
            at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MainPage.render(MainPage.java:63)
            at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:59)
            at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:31)
            at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:58)
            at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:176)
            at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:370)
            at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createAndGetPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:166)
            at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doGet(MapPrinterServlet.java:97)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
            at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
            at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
            at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
            at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
            at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/ (spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/)
            at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.checkSecurity(HTTPMapReader.java:136)
            at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.<init>(HTTPMapReader.java:76)
            at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.TileableMapReader.<init>(TileableMapReader.java:42)
            at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.OsmMapReader.<init>(OsmMapReader.java:50)
            at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.OsmMapReader$Factory.create(OsmMapReader.java:43)
            at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.MapReaderFactoryFinder.create(MapReaderFactoryFinder.java:36)
            at org.mapfish.print.map.MapChunkDrawer.renderImpl(MapChunkDrawer.java:120)
            at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.render(ChunkDrawer.java:55)
            at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.tableLayout(ChunkDrawer.java:49)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:855)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1978)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:999)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:993)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:981)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:583)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:831)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:964)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1986)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:999)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:993)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:981)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(PdfDocument.java:2717)
            at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:759)
            ... 111 more
        Caused by: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/
            at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.checkSecurity(HTTPMapReader.java:133)
            ... 133 more
```

Here is the config.yml file:

```
    #===========================================================================
    # allowed DPIs
    #===========================================================================
    dpis: [75, 150, 300,254,72]

    #===========================================================================
    # the allowed scales
    #===========================================================================
    scales:
      - 25000
      - 50000
      - 100000
      - 200000
      - 500000
      - 1000000
      - 2000000
      - 4000000

    #===========================================================================
    # the list of allowed hosts
    #===========================================================================
    hosts:
      - !localMatch
        dummy: true
      - !ipMatch
        ip: www.camptocamp.org
      - !dnsMatch
        host: demo.opengeo.org
        port: 80
      - !dnsMatch
        host: terraservice.net
        port: 80
      - !dnsMatch
        host: sigma.openplans.org
      - !dnsMatch
        host: demo.mapfish.org

    layouts:
      Legal:
        mainPage:
          pageSize: LEGAL
          items:
            - !map
              spacingAfter: 30
              width: 440
              height: 483
      #===========================================================================
      A4 portrait:
      #===========================================================================
        metaData:
    #      title: '${mapTitle}'
          author: 'MapFish print module'
          subject: 'Simple layout'
          keywords: 'map,print'
          creator: 'MapFish'

        titlePage:
          pageSize: A4
          items:
            - !text
              spacingAfter: 150
            - !text
              font: Helvetica
              fontSize: 40
              spacingAfter: 100
              align: center
              text: '${layout}'
            - !image
              maxWidth: 160
              maxHeight: 160
              spacingAfter: 100
              align: center
              url: http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/attachment/ticket/3/logo_v8_sphere.svg?format=raw

          footer: &commonFooter
            height: 30
            items:
              - !columns
                config:
                  cells:
                    - paddingBottom: 5   
                items:
                  - !text
                    backgroundColor: #FF0000
                    align: left
                    text: a red box
                  - !text
                    align: right
                    text: 'Page ${pageNum}'
                  - !image
                    align: center
                    maxWidth: 100
                    maxHeight: 30
                    spacingAfter: 200
                    url: 'http://geoserver.org/img/geoserver-logo.png'

        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mainPage:
          pageSize: A4
          rotation: true
    #      header:
    #        height: 50
    #        items:
    #          - !text
    #            font: Helvetica
    #            fontSize: 30
    #            align: right
    #            text: '${layout}'
          items:
            - !text
              text: '${mapTitle}'
              fontSize: 30
              spacingAfter: 30
            - !map
              spacingAfter: 30
              width: 440
              height: 483
            - !columns
              # columns can have an absolute position. In that case, they need the 3 following fields:
              absoluteX: 410
              absoluteY: 310
              width: 100
              items:
                - !scalebar
                  type: bar
                  maxSize: 100
                  barBgColor: white
                  fontSize: 8
                  align: right
            - !text
              text: '${comment}'
              spacingAfter: 30
            - !attributes
              source: data
              spacingAfter: 30
              columnDefs:
                id:
                  columnWeight: 2
                  header: !text
                    text: ID
                    backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
                  cell: !text
                    text: '${id}'
                name:
                  columnWeight: 5
                  header: !text
                    text: Name
                    backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
                  cell: !columns
                    config:
                      cells:
                        - backgroundColor: '${nameBackgroundColor}'
                          borderWidth: 1
                          borderColor: '${nameBorderColor}'
                    items:
                      - !text
                        text: '${name}'
                icon:
                  columnWeight: 2
                  header: !text
                    text: Symbol
                    backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
                  cell: !image
                    align: center
                    maxWidth: 15
                    maxHeight: 15
                    url: 'http://www.mapfish.org/svn/mapfish/trunk/MapFish/client/mfbase/mapfish/img/${icon}.png'
            - !text
              font: Helvetica
              fontSize: 9
              align: right
              text: '1:${scale} ${now MM.dd.yyyy}'
          footer: *commonFooter
```

What do I need to do for printing to work??

Answer (score 0):

Your list of allowed hosts does not allow for you mapfish to print from http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/ (the hint is in your error log where it says `spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/`).

There is an additional config.yaml file that you can use as a template: https://github.com/GeoNode/geoserver-geonode-ext/blob/main/data/printing/config.yaml`

From that sample, it seems you should add the following under your `hosts:` section:

```
  - !dnsMatch
    host: a.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: b.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: c.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: d.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
```

I know you probably don't need this answer anymore, but since I am having a lot of trouble with the geoserver mapfish printing module myself, I thought someone else might use this as reference.